# iOS addLayer: how to layout right?

Tags: ios, swift, layout

When adding some dash line to the view of a viewController, by add sublayer.

Here is the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tmpLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tmpLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor;
        tmpLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2
        tmpLabel.addDashedBorders(padding: 50, y: tmpLabel.bounds.size.height * 0.5)
        // ......
}}


extension UIView {


    func addDashedBorders( padding x: CGFloat, y : CGFloat) {
        //Create a CAShapeLayer
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2
        shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [2,3]

        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.addLines(between: [CGPoint(x: x, y: y),
                                CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width * 0.5 - 50, y: y)])
        path.addLines(between: [CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width * 0.5 + 50, y: y),
                                CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width - x, y: y)])
        shapeLayer.path = path
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
}
```

The following image is in iPhoneX

[image: 000]

The code is hard-coded, and not good.

[image: 111]

I want to add the sub shape layer to the view , right beneath the label.

there is the code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tmpLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tmpLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor;
        tmpLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2
        view.addDashedBorder(padding: 50, y: tmpLabel.frame.origin.y)
        //...
}}


extension UIView {
    func addDashedBorder( padding x: CGFloat, y : CGFloat) {

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2
        shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [2,3]

        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.addLines(between: [CGPoint(x: x, y: y),
                                CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width - x, y: y)])
        shapeLayer.path = path
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
}
```

I tested in iPhoneX, there is a distance.

I tried `view.safeAreaInsets`, it is all zero.

What do I miss?

Comment: `view.addDashedBorder(padding: 50, y: tmpLabel.frame.origin.y)` ?? should be `tmpLabel.addDashedBorders(padding: 50,y: tmpLabel.frame.origin.y)`

Comment: just `view`,  `view` = `self.view` , when not in a closure.

Comment: The top one is different from bottom. The top is tmpLabel why the bottom is view?

Comment: I add borders to the label. The two label's size are different. I want to add the layer to `self.view`. Then the label is on the top of `self.view` with the label's size set properly, with one line added. When handling the top method, I had to add two lines.